# How can I use variables defined in the body of a function as argument to that function?

Tags: r

I'm working on this problem: The first person rolls 1 of 3 die and then a second person rolls 1 of the remaining 2 die. The die are 6 sided but with random numbers on each side (the numbers corresponding to each dice are listed in the sample for that dice).

```
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins <- function(n, k, c1, c2){

    red <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(3,3,3,3,3,6), n)))
    yellow <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(2,2,2,5,5,5), n)))     
    green <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(1,4,4,4,4,4), n))) 

    return(sum(c1 > c2))
}

approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 1000, red, green)
```

My function works when I replace `c1` and `c2` with the vectors in the function like `sum(red > green)`. However, when I run the function as is, it returns the error `"object 'red' not found"`. The goal would be to replace `c1` and `c2` with whatever colors I define when calling the function.

Comment: You can't call it with `red` if the `red` object isn't created until the function runs (and only in the function's environment, anyway). The function doesn't do anything with the `red`/`yellow`/`green` variables, either, which is presumably not what you want.

Comment: You probably need `approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 3, 'red', 'green')` and `return(sum(get(c1) > get(c2)))`

Comment: @akrun Or capture `c1` and `c2` as expressions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is fairly advanced R. Note that `red` and `green` are not defined in your parent frame, so in regular programming this wouldn't work. However, it does work if you capture them as expressions and then evaluate once `red`, `green`, and `yellow` exist. Here's one way to do it:

```
library(rlang)
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins <- function(n, k, c1, c2){
  c1 <- enexpr(c1)
  c2 <- enexpr(c2)

  red <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(3,3,3,3,3,6), n)))
  yellow <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(2,2,2,5,5,5), n)))     
  green <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(1,4,4,4,4,4), n))) 

  # note: added divide by k to calculate probability
  return(sum(eval(c1) > eval(c2))/k)
}

set.seed(1234)
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 1000, red, green)
[1] 0.299
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `base R` by passing as a string and then use `get` to get the values

```
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins <- function(n, k, c1, c2){

   red <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(3,3,3,3,3,6), n)))
   yellow <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(2,2,2,5,5,5), n)))     
    green <- replicate(k, sum(sample(c(1,4,4,4,4,4), n))) 

   return(sum(get(c1) > get(c2)))
}

approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 3, 'red', 'green')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Non-standard evaluation

Create a list `L` made up of the three components `red`, `yellow` and `green`.
Then the indicated expressions can be used to convert the non-standard input
to character strings which are used to look up the appropriate component in L.

```
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins <- function(n, k, c1, c2){

    L <- list(red = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(3,3,3,3,3,6), n))),
              yellow = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(2,2,2,5,5,5), n))),
              green = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(1,4,4,4,4,4), n))))

    c1 <- deparse(substitute(c1))  ## 
    c2 <- deparse(substitute(c2))  ##

    sum(L[[c1]] > L[[c2]])
}

approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 1000, red, green)
```

### Standard Evaluation

To use standard evaluation (rather than the non-standard used above) we  would pass `"red"` and `"green"` rather than `red` and `green` and then we no longer need the two lines marked with ## above so the code simplifies to:

```
approximated.probability.that.c1.wins <- function(n, k, c1, c2){

    L <- list(red = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(3,3,3,3,3,6), n))),
              yellow = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(2,2,2,5,5,5), n))),
              green = replicate(k, sum(sample(c(1,4,4,4,4,4), n))))

    sum(L[[c1]] > L[[c2]])
}

approximated.probability.that.c1.wins(1, 1000, "red", "green")
```

### Using environments

Although as a rule it is best not to muck with environments, an alternative to defining `L` would be to go with the original code in the question but replace the last line of the body with:

```
e <- environment()
sum(e[[c1]] > e[[c2]])
```

`e` contains all the variables in the current function.  This would apply to the standard evaluation section and also the non-standard evaluation using the lines marked ##.